# System constantly reboots after install

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a new computer Victus 15-fb036nf with dual boot. Unfortunately, I'm getting many issues.

1. When I run Try Ubuntu and Install on the pendrive, my computer reboots in cycles.
2. I could install ubuntu using the Ubuntu (Safe graphics) mode
3. Whenever I try to boot on Ubuntu, I get the following errors.

```
Dec 22 01:34:35 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.28**.EC0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
Dec 22 01:34:35 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
Dec 22 01:34:35 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.GPP3.WLAN._PRR], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
Dec 22 01:34:35 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
Dec 22 01:34:35 ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:36 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Dec 22 01:34:38 ubuntu kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
Dec 22 01:34:41 ubuntu kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
Dec 22 01:34:41 ubuntu kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
Dec 22 01:34:42 ubuntu kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
Dec 22 01:34:42 ubuntu kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware init done
Dec 22 01:34:42 ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
Dec 22 01:36:07 ubuntu ubiquity[2088]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^oem-config/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=Driver:File >
Dec 22 01:36:07 ubuntu ubiquity[2088]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^keyboard-configuration/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=>
Dec 22 01:36:07 ubuntu ubiquity[2088]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^console-setup/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=Driver:Fi>
Dec 22 01:36:10 ubuntu systemd[2031]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Dec 22 01:36:10 ubuntu pulseaudio[2040]: Error opening PCM device _ucm0004.hw:acp: No such device
Dec 22 01:41:31 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1750]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
```

4. After those errors, the computer boots. I get around 5 seconds when I can move the mouse. Then the computer reboots on its own.

I updated the Bios and installed all the updates I could from Windows and Ubuntu, but couldn't get better results.

What should I do?

Comment: From Safe Graphics mode, did you also choose to install the restricted drivers? Those are required for nVidia and some WiFi chips. Do you have NVMe drive & did you update its firmware?

Comment: I did select the option to install the restricted drivers. Also, the safe graphics mode was not available anymore once the Ubuntu install was over. **But**, I could start a recovery mode where I had access to the terminal and could run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515`. This solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help because I didn't know what was the exact root cause of my problem. I thought that it was related to the Bios.